# Perl - DateTime module - How to compare two DateTime's for a 24 hour time lapse

Tags: perl, datetime

I saved a DateTime stamp to my database:

```
2015-02-23T16:59:25
```

I have a new DateTime Stamp which represents current time.

```
2015-02-24T16:59:25
```

I need to compare the two with DateTime to check if 24 hours has passed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use DateTime;

my $longenough;

Testing123();
exit;
sub Testing123{
my $yesterday = DateTime->now;
$yesterday->add( days => -1 ); 

 #This $yesterday time gets saved to my database.
 #For question purposes, I'll just pass it along instead of from db. 

CheckLapse($yesterday);

if ($longenough eq 'y'){ print qq~24 hours have passed<br />~; }
else{print qq~24 hours have not passed<br />~;}
}

sub CheckLapse{
$yesterday = shift;
my $now = DateTime->now;

# leftovers from many many hours of different attempts from my old bramaged drain

# my $elapse = $now - $yesterday;
# $now->subtract_duration( $yesterday ) ;
# $TimeLapse = $elapse->in_units('seconds'); #Left over from another try
# print "Elapsed time : ".$elapse->in_units('seconds')."m\n";

##  I need to compare the two times and pass $longenough y/n back:

if ($TimeLapse >= [24 hours whatever seconds minutes to do calc]){
$longenough = 'y';
}
else {$longenough = 'n';}
return $longenough;
}
exit;
```

I have read and read the cpan DateTime docs and tried everything except for obviously, the correct solution. 
I just keep getting errors like "Can't call method "yada yada" without a package or object reference".

Could someone educate me here?

Comment: Just subtract 24 hours from now (just like you do in Testing123), and then compare that with the value. You don't need to compute the difference between the values and now - you just need to work out a single point in time which is your cutoff.

Comment: Tried that. I don't know how to compare them. That is why I am here, out of complete frustration after 11 hours of attempts.

Comment: You really need to `use warnings` at the top of your Perl programs, as well as indenting them properly so that you, as well as others who read your code, can understand how it is structured.

Comment: @OldDogLearningNewPerlTricks: I can't believe it's really that hard to compare values. I'd expect just `>` to work. Perhaps you should try just a *very* simple example which just takes `DateTime->now` and `DateTime->now->add( days => -1 )` and compares them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct a DateTime object from your string as follows:

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $dt_format = DateTiFormat::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
   time_zone => 'local',
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $dt_format->parse_datetime('2015-02-23T16:59:25');
```

Then you can check if it's 24 hours old like this:

```
my $now = DateTime->now( time_zone => $dt->time_zone );
if  ($dt->clone->add( hours => 24 ) >= $now) {
   # It's been more than 24 hours.
   ...
}
```

---

Now, the above does a lot of work every time you check if 24 hours have passed. If you do this repeatedly, you can use reduce the workload as follows:

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $dt_format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
   time_zone => 'local',
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $dt_format->parse_datetime('2015-02-23T16:59:25');
$dt->add( hours => 24 );
my $target_time = $dt->epoch;
```

Then check then simplifies to

```
if  ($target_time >= time)
   # It's been more than 24 hours.
   ...
}
```

---

You probably want `->add( days => 1 )` (same time on the next calendar day) instead of `->add( hours => 24 )`.

Comment: Trying this now.  I was really confused with clone.

Comment: `clone` prevents `$dt1` from being changed by `add`.

Comment: Can't call method "time_zone" without a package or object reference

Comment: Yes use strict and warnings. I assigned $yesterday in both occurrences of $dt.

Comment: Makes no sense to me. I changed $yesterday back to $dt in both occurrences and made no difference. I even set $dt='2015-02-23T16:59:25'; to no avail. (instead of shifting)

Comment: `'2015-02-23T16:59:25'` creates a string, not a DateTime object. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I am waiting for DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm to be installed on server. Only DateTime was installed.

Comment: You can create the DateTime object without that module, but it's shorter using that module.

Comment: Yeah, I am not smart enough to do that (create the DateTime object without that module) however, an example would help. That said, YOU ARE A GENIUS. The module is now installed and is working. Let me run some tests before I mark as answered. I am sure all will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) module is enormous and slow, and is a complete toolbox for anything date-time related. [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) is a much lighter weight core module (so it shouldn't need to be installed) and is quite up to this task.

Here's a demonstration of a solution using `Time::Piece`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece ();
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_DAY';

my ($t1, $t2) = qw/
  2015-02-23T16:59:25
  2015-02-24T16:59:25
/;

my $diff = delta_time($t1, $t2);

say $diff >= ONE_DAY ? 'over one day' : 'less than one day';

sub delta_time {
  my ($t1, $t2) = map Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), @_;
  return $t2 > $t1 ? $t2 - $t1 : $t1 - $t2;
}
```

**output**

```
over one day
```

Comment: @ikegami With `Time::Seconds`, one day is (perhaps naively) always 24 hours: "The methods make the assumption that there are 24 hours in a day, 7 days in a week, 365.24225 days in a year and 12 months in a year."

Comment: @OldDogLearningNewPerlTricks: I have assumed that what you want is an elapsed time of a day. If it is indeed 24 hours as you have requested (there is a difference on days where daylight saving time starts or stops) then you can change it by writing `use Time::Seconds 'ONE_HOUR'` and `$diff >= ONE_HOUR * 24` instead.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I believe that `ONE_YEAR` should in fact be `31556952` (365.2425 days)

Comment: @ikegami: It's a solar year.

Comment: @ikegami Looks like the developers used a [recommendation for leap years](http://www.tondering.dk/claus/cal/gregorian.php#fourthousand) that has never actually been adopted: "It has been suggested (by the astronomer John Herschel (1792-1871) among others) that a better approximation to the length of the tropical year would be 365 969/4000 days = 365.24225 days. This would dictate 969 leap years every 4000 years, rather than the 970 leap years mandated by the Gregorian calendar. This could be achieved by dropping one leap year from the Gregorian calendar every 4000 years..."

Comment: @ikegami: So you're saying that the solar year is never useful? I know many that would disagree!

Comment: I don't think your astrophysicist will use Time::Seconds to get the length of a solar year, so yeah, I'm saying noone will ever use `Time::Seconds::ONE_YEAR` in a way that makes sense.

Comment: `Time::Piece->strptime` parses the date/time in the GMT/UTC zone unless it contains a %z or %Z format specifier and thus the above is incorrect if it's crossing DST.

Comment: @ikegami: I use it all the time to convert annual/monthly quantities into their mean daily/weekly equivalent. In particular I use `$per_week = $per_year / 12 * 0.23`, which is pretty much the same.